# RTSP to RTMP streaming

Tags: video, rtmp, rtsp

I am trying to set up a server for converting a video stream, live. The input stream is in RTSP format, and the output should be RTMP (to use in a Flash application).

I've had a look at crtmp, which seems like a good solution; however, I can't figure out the right configuration by myself (the .lua file). Is there an easy way to set it up as to convert the stream from RTSP to RTMP?

Alternatively, is there an easier-to-use video server (either Linux or Windows) that is also free, and that would do the same thing?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4010019/rtsp-to-rtmp-streaming

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the long story short. I don't know yet the details about your particular camera, but I have a nice working example for you:

1. Open the configuration file and replace the externalStreams node from flvplaybackapplication with this one:

   ```
       externalStreams =                                                   
       {                                                                   
           {                                                               
               uri="rtsp://fms20.mediadirect.ro/live2/realitatea/realitatea",
               localStreamName="test1",                                    
               forceTcp=true                                               
           },                                                              
           {                                                               
               uri="rtsp://fms20.mediadirect.ro/live/utv/utv",             
               localStreamName="test2",                                    
               forceTcp=false                                              
           }                                                               
       },
   ```

After that, use jwplayer, flow player, etc. to playback the stream. The full RTMP URIs are:

```
 rtmp://ip/live/test1
```

or

```
 rtmp://ip/live/test2
```

As you can see, those streams are 2 RTSP streams. One is RTP/RTCP over UDP (forceTcp=false) and one is RTP/RTCP over RTSP (forceTcp=true). Because RTSP is over TCP, you get that flag to true.

Needless to say, you MAY experience playback glitches and issues caused by the fact that those 2 streams are very far away from you (they are here in Romania).

Hope it helps

Comment: I removed the download link, dropbox isn't exactly a trusted source. If you do want to link to something then link it against a official site of the product.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for. However, I still have a problem which is adressed in [this Google Group](http://groups.google.com/group/c-rtmp-server/browse_thread/thread/c8f903dcf2a7a4c3)

Answer (score 1):

I'd try [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/) or [Wowza](http://www.wowza.com/media-server) myself.

Comment: I'm not sure VLC supports streaming to RTMP? But in case it does, how do I open the "new" stream coming from it? As for Wowza, it's not free...

Comment: VLC does not support RTMP.

Comment: @Andrew: "VLC supports RTMP" -- https://wiki.videolan.org/Real_Time_Messaging_Protocol/

Comment: Yes @David Cary, but last time I checked, VLC, although able to stream RTMP, it was unable to broadcast as RTMP.  The link you posted shows how to read from an RTMP stream, which is not what was required by the OP.

Answer (score 0):

To Convert RTSP to RTMP Streams, use Wowza Media Server and here is the restreaming guide http://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?39